# SQL select if based on another talbles match

Tags: php, sql, select

I have two tables safe_customers safe_link

Both have a Id placed to match eachother in lookup.

safe_customers "ID" and safe_link "SecondID"

I would like to have a query that selects rows in safe_customers only if the **PHP $var** matches **"FirstID"** in safe_link and the fields representing the ID in both the tables match.

**safe_customers**

```
--Name---ID---Age---Date

--Bob--- 33---32---10-32-90

--Kalr--- 21---22---10-2-90

--Bob--- 58---32---10-12-33
```

**safe_link**

```
--FirstID---SecondID---

--   10   ---   21  ---

--   11   ---   33  ---

--   54   ---   58  ---
```

So **if $var** is **10** it would return the row in safe_customers with **ID 21**

```
--Kalr--- 21---22---10-2-90
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select sc.* From safe_customers sc
Inner JOin safe_link sl on sc.ID=sl.secondId
Where sl.FirstID=@FirstID
```

Where @FirstID is your  PHP $var

**Edit:**

If want to combine results of two queries then do:

```
Select sc.* From safe_customers sc
Inner JOin safe_link sl on sc.ID=sl.secondId
Where sl.FirstID=@FirstID
Union
Select * From safe_customers Where Name= 'Bob' and Age=32
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you !!! It works. Now for the rest. I thought I would be able to figure it out if I had this but I guess not.. 
I also need to select additional rows from safe_customer if Colnm "Name" is "Bob" and Colnm "Age" is "32" on safe_customers, this wouldnt include the query safe_link

Comment: Change your wording to sql query and you will get your result. Select * From safe_customers Where Name= 'Bob' and Colnm Age=32

Comment: I need both these selects to be a single mysql query

Comment: I would but, I am new here at the forms. It displays Vote Up requires 15 reputation.